how to query based on 3 criteria refers to more than one record or duplicate record in VB.NET
I'm Trying to query based on 3 criteria refers to more than one record or duplicate record in VB.NET
So the criteria I mean are: ID , DATE , INOUT
So I want to query more than one record or duplicate record referring to these 3 criteria
I don't want to use functions in MS Access because I use SQL for VB.NET.
Please Guide me.
Thanks
SELECT ABSEN.ID AS [ID],
     MASTERID.NAMEID AS [NAMEID],
     MASTERID.POSITIONID AS [POSITIONID],
     ABSEN.DATE AS [DATE],
     format(ABSEN.DATE,'dddd') AS [DAYS],
     ABSEN.TIME AS [TIME],
     ABSEN.FP AS [FP],
     ABSEN.INOUT AS [INOUT],
     ABSEN.OTHERS1 AS [OTHERS1],
     ABSEN.OTHERS1 AS [OTHERS2],
     ABSEN.STATUS AS [STATUS] 
FROM ABSEN 
  INNER JOIN 
     MASTERID 
  ON ABSEN.ID = MASTERID.ID 
  WHERE MASTERID.POSITIONID='STAFF'";

RESULT CODE
ID  NAMEID  POSITIONI DATE             DAYS          TIME          FP   INOUT   OTHERS1 OTHERS2 STATUS
5008    A   STAFF   06-04-24         Saturday   07:34:29           1    IN      0       0      PRESENT
5008    A   STAFF   06-04-24         Saturday   15:00:28           1    IN      0       0      PRESENT
5009    B   STAFF   06-04-24         Saturday   08:02:06           1    IN      0       0      PRESENT
5009    B   STAFF   07-04-24         Sunday     15:00:16           1    IN      0       0      PRESENT
5009    B   STAFF   07-04-24         Sunday     16:33:44           1    OUT     0       0      PRESENT

Table ABSEN
ID  DATE             TIME          FP   INOUT   OTHERS1 OTHERS2 STATUS
5008    06-04-24    07:34:29        1   IN          0   0      PRESENT
5008    06-04-24    15:00:28        1   IN          0   0      PRESENT
5009    06-04-24    08:02:06        1   IN          0   0      PRESENT
5009    07-04-24    15:00:16        1   IN          0   0      PRESENT
5009    07-04-24    16:33:44        1   OUT         0   0      PRESENT


Table MASTERID
ID  NAMEID  POSITIONID  
5008    A   STAFF        
5009    B   STAFF


desired result

ID  NAMEID  POSITIONID   DATE     DAYS      TIME      FP  INOUT OTHERS1 OTHERS2 STATUS
5008    A   STAFF       06-04-24 Saturday   07:34:29    1   IN  0        0      PRESENT
5008    A   STAFF       06-04-24 Saturday   15:00:28    1   IN  0        0      PRESENT

I used the SQL code below but the results did not match the desired results
SELECT ABSEN.ID, ABSEN.Date, ABSEN.INOUT, Count(*) AS Expr1
FROM ABSEN
GROUP BY ABSEN.ID, ABSEN.Date, ABSEN.INOUT
HAVING (((Count(*))>1));

result from code
ID       Date     INOUT Expr1
5008    06-Apr-24   IN  2


I want to query more than one record referring to these 3 criteria ... and your result is five records, so what is missing?

Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read. Make it easy to assist you, add line break and fix the indentation.

What do you mean by SQL for VB.NET?

The SQL uses criteria with Status and PositionID - not the 3 fields you mentioned in narrative. What rules should be applied to these 3 fields? What do you mean by "query more than one record referring to these 3 criteria". What have you tried?

@Gustav , how to query based on 3 criteria refers to more than one record or duplicate record in VB.NET So look for duplicate records with where condition 3 criteria

@ShahramAlemzadeh ,
so I don't want to use the SQL function because I use the SQL in VB.net

@June7 , how to query based on 3 criteria refers to more than one record or duplicate record in VB.NET so look for duplicate records with where condition 3 criteria . What have you tried?
I have updated the post but the results are not yet the desired results

Build another query that joins ABSEN, MASTERID, and your aggregate query.

@June7 , please guide me

Use Access query designer to get correct syntax then you can use the SQL in VB.net code.
